# How to calculate excel circular reference formula in php

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, circular-reference

We are converting excel sheet to web base so we need to apply the same excel(circular reference) logic in web base application development.

When we have to calculate a value for the F3 cell it uses the G3 cell's value and the G3 cell's formula also uses the F3 cell value. we need to implement this logic in PHP.

In excel we have the following formula:

`F3 = 0/590.07+(1.45+0.055*G3/1000)/8.42-0` (Result is = 0.21096279)

`G3 = (38.2-F3*5.87)/(6.23+E3)*1000` (Result is = 5932.848864)

Maximum Iterations: 100

Maximum Change: 0.001

Any help to calculate that same result in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Excel` circular references only are possible to calculate if iterative calculation is enabled. And defaults are: Use up to 100 iterations and stop iteration if the values change is lower than 0.001. So you need to do the same.

`VBA`code which can be taken as pseudo code:

```
Sub CIRCULAR()
 E3 = 0
 F3 = 0
 G3 = 0
 maxDelta = 0.001
 For i = 0 To 100
  F3a = F3
  G3a = G3
  F3 = 0 / 590.07 + (1.45 + 0.055 * G3 / 1000) / 8.42 - 0
  G3 = (38.2 - F3 * 5.87) / (6.23 + E3) * 1000
  If Abs(F3a - F3) < maxDelta And Abs(G3a - G3) < maxDelta Then Exit For
 Next i
 resultF3 = F3
 resultG3 = G3
End Sub
```

Btw.: Your results only are correct if `E3` contains `0`. And it is not clear why the terms `0/590.07` and `-0` are in formula in `F3` as they are useless at all.

Comment: The formula value for F Cell is dynamical, it's not always 0 @Axel Richter.

Answer (score 0):

Make it non circular and then attribute values to F3 and G3.

Iteratively recalculate the values based on the results until you have the results needed.